# How to solve the ascii problems when I try to download pictures?

Tags: python-3.x

Here are my codes:

```
import re,urllib
from urllib import request, parse

def gh(url):
html=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
return html   

def gi(x):
    r=r'src="(.+?\.jpg)"'
    imgre=re.findall(r, x)
    y=0
    for iu in imgre:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(iu, '%s.jpg' %y)
        y=y+1

va=gh('http://tieba.baidu.com/p/3497570603')
print(gi(va))
```

when it is running, it occurs:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u65e5' in position 873: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have decoded the content of website with 'utf-8' which turns into string, and where is the 'ascii codec' problem from?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the HTML content of http://tieba.baidu.com/p/3497570603 contains references to `.png` images so the non-greedy regular expression matches long strings of text such as

```
http://static.tieba.baidu.com/tb/editor/images/client/image_emoticon28.png" ><br><br><br><br>
...
title="蓝钻"><img src="http://imgsrc.baidu.com/forum/pic/item/bede9735e5dde711c981db20a0efce1b9f1661d5.jpg
```

Calling the `urlretrieve()` method with URLs consisting of long strings containing non-ASCII characters results in the `UnicodeEncodeError` being thrown while trying to convert the URL argument to ASCII.

A better regular expression to avoid matching too much text would be

```
 r=r'src="([^"]+?\.jpg)"'
```

#### Debugging

In the spirit of [teaching someone to fish rather than simply giving them a fish for one day](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day._Teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime), I’d recommend that you use `print` statements to debug problems such as this. I was able to diagnose this particular issue by replacing the `urllib.request.urlretrieve(iu, '%s.jpg' %y)` line with `print(iu)`.